# Building html calendar view using django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to build a calendar view using django and trying to avoid writing any html tags inside my view. I found a code that helped me get there,

```
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta, time
import calendar

year=2011
month=12
change=None

# init variables
cal = calendar.Calendar()
month_days = cal.itermonthdays(year, month)
lst = [[]]
week = 0

# make month lists containing list of days for each week
# each day tuple will contain list of entries and 'current' indicator
for day in month_days:
    lst[week].append((day))
    if len(lst[week]) == 7:
        lst.append([])
        week += 1
```

and in my view, i did the following

```
<div class="calendar_panel_bottom_noborder">
    <span class="month">Juny 2011</span>
    <span class="day_name">S</span>
    <span class="day_name">M</span>
    <span class="day_name">T</span>
    <span class="day_name">W</span>
    <span class="day_name">T</span>
    <span class="day_name">F</span>
    <span class="day_name">S</span>
    {% for week in month_days %}

        {% for day in week %}
            <span class="date">{{ day }}</span>
        {% endfor %}

    {% endfor %}
    <div class="clear"></div>


</div>
```

Now, the above code is printing the calendar as per the month and year parameters but they are appearing wrong. When I compare it with the calendar, using december 2011, the first day of the month starts at thursday while in calendar its starting on wednesday. can anyone help point out what I did wrong here?

**UPDATE**

It seems like the problem is coming from itermonthdays. I tried to do the following

```
>>> month_days = cal.itermonthdays(2011, 12)
>>> for day in month_days:
...  print day
... 
0
0
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
31
0
```

I don't know if I should change some sort of a settings or initiate the class differently. But, the output should start with 4 zeros and end with none based on my PC calendar it shows that december 2011 starts on a thursday which is the 5th day of the week therefore there should be 4 zeros before the count starts. hmm any advice on how i can tackle this issue?

Comment: Not remotely connected to the question, but why are you using `<div>` and `<span>` to represent tabular data?

Comment: i have a css class that takes care of the representation. It displays the output a table,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include

```
cal.setfirstweekday(6)
```

before

```
monthdays = ...
```

According to [python documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/calendar.html), ...

> By default, these calendars have Monday as the first day of the week,
>   and Sunday as the last (the European convention).

Comment: thank you very much. This is exactly what I've been looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like your problem is simply that `itermonthdays` starts with Monday instead of Sunday. You can confirm this by temporarily replacing

```
itermonthdays
```

with

```
itermonthdates
```

and

```
lst[week].append(day)
```

with

```
lst[week].append(day.strftime("%A")))
```

This should temporarily replace day numbers with day of the week names.

**Edit:** One possible solution to your problem is to initialize `lst` to `[[0]]` and then set `lst=lst[:-1]` at the end of your loop.

Comment: i tried to itermonthdates(2011, 12) but i got dates starting from Nov-28 until Jan-1st. Which I don't get :S

Comment: what I noticed that am always one day short. I tested on several months

Answer (score 0):

> When I compare it with the calendar, using december 2011, the first day of the month starts at thursday while in calendar its starting on wednesday. can anyone help point out what I did wrong here?

I have bad new for you, the first day of december 2011 is thursday, according my windows calendar

Comment: the code is showing me wednesday as the first day of december. It should be showing thursday

Answer (score 0):

I recently made a calendar to display latest month days

```
views.py
def index(request):
    x=str(datetime.now())
    d0 = datetime(year=date.fromisoformat(x.split(' ')[0]).year, month=date.fromisoformat(x.split(' ')[0]).month, day=1)
    d1 = datetime(year=date.fromisoformat(x.split(' ')[0]).year, month=date.fromisoformat(x.split(' ')[0]).month+1, day=1)
    cal = Calendar()
    lst = [[]]
    week = 0
    cal.setfirstweekday(0)
    monthly_days = cal.itermonthdates(date.fromisoformat(x.split(' ')[0]).year, date.fromisoformat(x.split(' ')[0]).month)
    month1=date.fromisoformat(x.split(' ')[0]).month
    year1=date.fromisoformat(x.split(' ')[0]).year
    for day in monthly_days:
        if len(lst[week])<7:
            if int(day.strftime('%m'))!=int(str(month1)):
                lst[week].append(' ')
            else:
                lst[week].append(day.strftime('%d'))
        else:
            week+=1
            if int(day.strftime('%m'))!=int(str(month1)):
                lst.append([' '])
            else:
                lst.append([day.strftime('%d')])
    return render(request,'base.html',{'monthly_days':lst})
```

base.html

```
<body>
    <h1>
        Hi!!!!
    </h1>
    <h2>
        Welcome to Calendar
    </h2>
        <div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><span class="day_name">M</span></td>
                    <td><span class="day_name">T</span></td>
                    <td><span class="day_name">W</span></td>
                    <td><span class="day_name">T</span></td>
                    <td><span class="day_name">F</span></td>
                    <td><span class="day_name">S</span></td>
                    <td><span class="day_name">S</span></td>
                </tr>
                {% for week in monthly_days %}
                    <tr>
                    {% for day in week %}
                        <td><span class="date">{{ day }}</span></td>
                    {% endfor %}
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </table>
        </div>
</body>
```

This is for a tabular format